# Get object from value of HTML input

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML form whose submit button is an input element. The redirect URL lies within an object in the input's value. I want to get the redirect URL using jQuery so I can modify it.

```
<input name="input_name" type="hidden" value="{"pageName":"Page Name", "redirectUrl":"www.site.com"}">
```

Comment: What have you tried? A well-formed question includes what code you've tried and the issue you had with it; it's not advised to just post some sample input and ask for someone to write the code to produce your desired output.

Comment: Set input id="input_id" and $("#inputid").val().Split(":"); Do you want to this?

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse($('input[name="hs_context"]').val()); console.log(obj. redirectUrl);`

Comment: @Stevangelista Yep – I've tried `var input = $('input[name="input_name"]'); input.val("redirectUrl");` but it just returns the value of the whole object

Answer (score 0):

I am going to be honest I have never seen an object inside of a value attribute, even if you can do that I don't believe its the best way to do things.

From what I see on form submission you are trying to get a URL from a hidden field and do something with it.

I would consider refactoring your HTML a bit as a start, make your submit button an actual button with type of submit and have your data sit in two seperate hidden inputs with the data inside value.

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="redirectUrl" value="www.url.com" />
  <input type="hidden" name="pageName" value="page name" />
  <button type="submit">Submit form</button>     
</form>
```

Then inside your jQuery prevent the default submission event and grab the values.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const pageName = $(this).find('input[name=pageName]').val()
    const redirectUrl = $(this).find('input[name=redirectUrl]').val()
})
```

If you need to keep the button as an input for whatever reason consider using data-ids to refactor the html

```
<input 
    type="hidden" 
    name="input_name"
    data-pageName="pageName"
    data-redirectUrl="www.url.com" />
```

Then inside the submission handler you can access the data like this

```
const hiddenInput = document.querySelector('input[name="input_name"]')
const pageName = hiddenInput.dataset.pageName
const url = hiddenInput.dataset.redirectUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get the value and turn the string into an object
var obj = JSON.parse($('input[name="input_name"]').val());

// Now you can access any property
console.log(obj.redirectUrl); // www.site.com
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Notice the single quotes used in value assignment, you've used double quotes -->
<input name="input_name" type="hidden" value='{"pageName":"Page Name", "redirectUrl":"www.site.com"}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, Use a combination of nested single qoutes and doubles qoutes in such cases.

```js
var redirectUrl = $.parseJSON($("input[name=input_name]").val()).redirectUrl;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input name="input_name" type="hidden" value='{"pageName":"Page Name", "redirectUrl":"www.site.com"}'>
```